# Autorenewable In App Purchases - Link from my App to appropriate Settings in App-Store App

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase

In my App I am using autorenewable In App Purchases. From a screen within my App I want to have a link into the App-Store App exactly to the point where the user can manage settings for subscriptions he has done with my app (for instance change the settings from automatically renew to manually renew).

Is that possible? If yes - how would the link look like?

If it is not possible to switch directly to these setting, how deep can I link to it? Maybe opening the App-Store App only or maybe opening the general subscription setting screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from Apple Suport:

"Use the following url to directly link to the Manage Subscriptions page in the App Store from within your application:

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions"

This is mentioned in the iTunesConnect Developer Guide, ["In-App Purchases"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html)